# Reformatting an wysiwyg generated html file

Tags: asp.net, css

I am reading in what i thought was just basic text from an .html file and i want to display it on a asp.net webpage.

I put some css formatting but it doesn't seem to fully work.  I got to the bottom of it as the issue is now that i look at what i thought was raw text turns out to be:

```
<SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt">
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal                                 
align=center><SPAN    style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt"><?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = 
"urn:schemas-  microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></SPAN></P><SPAN 
style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt"><o:p> 
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal align=center><SPAN   
style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt">General Manager’s Corner<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>  
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal align=center><SPAN   
style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt">July 2009<o:p></o:p></SPAN></P>  
<P style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt" class=MsoNormal align=center><SPAN   
style="FONT-SIZE: 16pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></P>
```

this looks like its coming from microsoft word or something with some inline formatting.

is there anyway i can either:

1. Remove all the inline formatting
2. have my css override the inline formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just hand coded something that did a bunch of find and replaces.  spent too much time trying third party tools that all almost did the job.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small API for stripping HTML generated by word called [WordOff](http://wordoff.org/api). Maybe you can use that one?

Answer (score 0):

Inline formatting is more specific so I am pretty sure it will win out everytime when it comes to CSS.

As for removing the actual inline formatting itself a quick google showed up a few options you could use some free some not

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the **!important** hack to override the inline styles in your CSS.

As for removing the inline formatting, you could try Googling [paste from word](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paste+from+word) or come up with your own regular expression to discard everything in a tag after the tagname itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply several simple regex patterns to remove the formating:

For style:

```
style="[^"]*"
```

For class and align:

```
(align|class)=[A-Za-z]*
```

To play with the expressions you can use this on-line tool: http://www.regextester.com/